Is 谈何易 an abbreviation of 谈何容易 occurring in one of 毛主席's poems?
Is 谈何易 an abbreviation of 谈何容易 occurring in one of 毛主席's poems?
see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBY8WaLgi_g 3:16
answer: 毛泽东诗词 https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%AF%9B%E6%B3%BD%E4%B8%9C%E8%AF%97%E8%AF%8D/31327

可以这样理解。另外，「易」字本身也有「簡單、不困難」（「容易」）的意思，比如成语「来之不易」等等，所以作「谈何易」也是合适的。
另一个角度看，具体到这首《满江红》的词，由于词调已定，从而词作的格律，包括每一句的字数是有规定的，从而将成语「谈何容易」缩写为三个字「谈何易」。
值得一提的是，成语「谈何容易」经历过一个演变过程。它的本义是「（在君王面前）谈说论议（、指陈得失）不可轻易从事」，此处「何容」应该连起来解释，后以「容易」连读，成为了我们现在常见的，也是毛泽东的词作里面的意思。参见《汉语大词典》：

谈何容易：本谓在君王面前谈说论议、指陈得失不可轻易从事。何容，岂可，怎能容许。《文选·东方朔〈非有先生论〉》：「先生曰：於戲，可乎哉？可乎哉？談何容易！」张铣注：「再言之者，所以言談之辭，何得輕易而爲之。」汉桓宽《盐铁论·箴石》：「賈生有言曰：『懇言則辭淺而不入，深言則逆耳而失指。』故曰：『談何容易。』談且不易，而況行之乎？」马非百简注：「談，説話。何容，怎能容許。易，輕易。」后以「容易」连读，意为说起来简单，做起来可并不那么容易。《文明小史》第十回：「周師韓聽了，鼻子裏撲嗤一笑道：『説的，談何容易！』」孙犁《澹定集·读冉淮舟近作散文》：「我们常说调查研究，调查研究，谈何容易！」


原文:
小小寰球，有几个苍蝇碰壁。嗡嗡叫，几声凄历，几声抽泣。蚂蚁缘槐夸大国，蚍蜉撼树谈何易。正西风落叶下长安，飞鸣镝。
多少事，从来急，天地转，光阴迫。一万年太久，只争朝夕。四海翻腾云水怒，五洲震荡风雷激，要扫除一切害人虫，全无敌。
"谈何易" is in the style of "Classical Chinese writing" which is equivalent to "谈何容易" of today.
Mao was educated and fluent in traditional Chinese literacies. Many of his works were written in the styles of the past - 詩/詞.
